# Mesh in Black even after applying a Texture

Tags: texturing

Folks,

I spent quite a bit of time carefully reading through several posts that seem relevant to my problem and actually trying out all suggested solutions to no avail.

Basically, I'm back to modding for Skyrim and just wanted to try getting a simple mesh imported to the game before I start creating actual armors and such. But the problem is I can't even get a texture show up on my experimental mesh. I didn't have this problem with Blender 2.49b, but now I'm using 2.76b (I admit I'm baffled with all the changes!).

Here's [the link to the .blend file](http://www.filedropper.com/skyrimbasemodstep3) (NSFW) for your scrutiny. I'd appreciate any tips/feedback as to how I can get the texture to show up on the custom mesh.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no lighting. A sun lamp can shine some light on your textures, both in texture and rendered view.

The reason the body texture shows up is that it's material has an emit value of 1.0, so it is 'emitting' it's texture as light, while the clothing has o.o emit. Note that the emit value doesn't emit a light that other objects interact with.

You could also enable shadeless.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to add that if `Indirect Liighting` is enabled in World settings, object which emits light will shine on other objects (it works only with `Approximate` AO calculating method though).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. :)